# Scissor congruence of two general tetrahedrons having mirror symmetry

Tags: polyhedra, discrete-geometry, polytopes

**Problem** : If $P,\ P'\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is two polyhedra which 
are congruent up to a mirror symmetry then prove that they are 
scissor congruent

**Proof** : We can cut polyhedron into a finite number of general tetrahedrons Hence this problem is reduced to case where $P,\ P$ are two general tetrahedrons But how can we finish the proof ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Note that triangle has incentor so that we have 3 pair of triangles having mirror symmetry We can generalize this on general tetrahedron